# iOS 5 : bug with loadHTMLString with style

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I have these lines of code:

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"<html><body><p \"style=\"font-size:%d; text-align:center; color:red; \
    direction:rtl;\">%@</p></body</html>", fontSize, thePage];
mailBody.text = thePage;
[self.page loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Styling didn't take any effect at all. So, `direction` isn't set, `color` is black instead of red and the `font-size` isn't set to the number I put in the variable. Yet, it's working in pre iOS 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem in your HTML

USE THIS

```
NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><p style=\"font-size:%d;text-align:center; color:red; direction:rtl;\">%@</p></body></html>",fontSize,thePage];
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem within his HTML?

Comment: an extra `"` in front of `style` and no closing bracket on `</body`